# What type of aileron is the AIrbus A380 equipped with?

Tags: airbus-a380, ailerons

The ailerons of the A380 seem to be in 2 pieces. What is its purpose?[image]

Comment: Actually, there are 3 ailerons (not 2). [This picture](http://i15.photobucket.com/albums/a357/thezeke/A380%20systems/604e00d1.png) shows them better. You can see the third one in your picture too.

Comment: What is the purpose of having 3 ailerons?

Comment: I guess the purpose is discussed in the question linked. If you feel that the other post does not answer your question, please edit yours and specify why this one is different than that one. It will be reopened then.

Comment: also relevant: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/11337/1467

Comment: This is a duplicate question but there *should not* be a need to downvote.