# Can new technology help planes dodge turbulence?

Tags: turbulence

With so many technological advancements happening in the aviation industry, will it be possible for airlines to smoothen the effects of turbulence, as turbulence cannot be eliminated?

The following news indicate the same:

[Smooth talk: How Qantas is ironing out the bumps](http://www.heraldsun.com.au/business/smooth-talk-how-qantas-is-ironing-out-the-bumps/news-story/8efdcad7af9b1a6cddc800ffdfb1cb97)

[Feathers in flight inspire anti-turbulence technology](https://www.rmit.edu.au/news/all-news/2014/november/antiturbulence-technology-inspired-by-feathers)

Comment: As a passenger I enjoy turbulence. I think it adds a little bit of excitement to an otherwise boring hours-long flight.

Comment: Are you asking about [alleviation systems](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11336/what-is-a-gust-alleviation-system) ?

Comment: Dodging, as in avoiding?

Comment: @kevin Do you like riding horses? :P